# El certificado remoto no es válido según el procedimiento de validación

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

Estoy tratando de invocar un webservice, con usuario y contraseña para consumir el servicio pero me arroja este error.

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. El certificado remoto no es
>   válido según el procedimiento de validación. Descripción: Excepción no
>   controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento
>   de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se
>   originó en el código.

**Detalles de la excepción:**

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: El certificado
>   remoto no es válido según el procedimiento de validación.

**Error de código fuente:**

> Línea 229:         Línea 230:        public
>   WebApplication2.WSComex.GetTokenResult oAuthorizeCmx(string appid,
>   string redirectUri, string User, string Pass, string dominio, string
>   scope) { Línea 231:            return
>   base.Channel.oAuthorizeCmx(appid, redirectUri, User, Pass, dominio,
>   scope); Línea 232:        } Línea 233:
>
> Archivo de origen: C:\Users\Roguime\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Service
>   References\WSComex\Reference.cs    Línea: 231

**Seguimiento de la pila:**

```
> [AuthenticationException: El certificado remoto no es válido según el
> procedimiento de validación.]   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
> +1821220    System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +6683688   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +49   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +51   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +184   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +132   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +59   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +49   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +51   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +184   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +132   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +59   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +49   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +51   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +184   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +132   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +59   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +49   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
> Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +162   
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
> lazyResult) +523   
> System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state) +42   
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx) +193   
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx) +21   
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +64   
> System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
> +795    System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +52    System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 size) +21   
> System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) +388
> 
> [WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: No se puede establecer una
> relación de confianza para el canal seguro SSL/TLS.]   
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1399   
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout) +68
> 
> [SecurityNegotiationException: No se pudo establecer una relación de
> confianza para el canal seguro SSL/TLS con la autoridad
> 'servedappdev.grupocomex.com.mx'.]   
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +153   
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type) +336   
> WebApplication2.WSComex.IComexNetSSO.oAuthorizeCmx(String appid,
> String redirectUri, String User, String Pass, String dominio, String
> scope) +0   
> WebApplication2.WSComex.ComexNetSSOClient.oAuthorizeCmx(String appid,
> String redirectUri, String User, String Pass, String dominio, String
> scope) in C:\Users\Roguime\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Service
> References\WSComex\Reference.cs:231   
> WebApplication2.Login.Acceso_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\Roguime\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Login.ascx.cs:47   
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109   
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +108   
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +10   
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
> sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13   
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> +31    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +3466
```

Comment: Deberías revisar bien la documentación de como consumir el ws
A simple vista parece que: -estas mandando claves erroneas
-al parecer debes tener un certificado ppfx
-el cerficado pfx esta mal creado A tu código no se le ve algo malo, siento que es mas por la cuestiones que cite arriba

Answer (score 3):

Por si alguién se topa con este mismo problema (ha sido mi caso) , yo lo he solucionado siguiendo las indicaciones que se comentan en este enlace: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/130308da-4092-4f21-8355-ee3c77a22f97/llamar-web-service-con-certificado?forum=netfxwebes

Se trata de establecer un handler para forzar la aceptación del certificado.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);


public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno mira el WS, solo lo mando llamar con este codigo no tengo control sobre el WS.
WS.WebServiceClient oAutCMX = new WS.WebServiceClient();
oAutCMX.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Usuario";
oAutCMX.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Contraseña";
Lresultado.Text = oAutCMX.oAuthorizeCmx("AppID", "www.google.com.mx", BoxUser.Text, BoxPws.Text, "SSG", "HomePrivado").ToString();

Comment: No es de tu código
Siento que debes tener un certificado pfx en tu máquina para poder usar el ws

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, esos certificados te los tiene que otorgar el propietario del web service, o hay alguna manera de generarlo en mi equipo?

Comment: El creador es quien te lo proporciona, una vez que lo tengas los debes instalar en tu máquina, y probar tu app

Answer (score 1):

Colocar ántes del clienteSMTP.Send(mail):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors){ return true; };
```

Comment: Lo único que hará esa línea es omitir las validaciones de certificados. **No es recomendable en ambientes productivos**.

Answer (score 1):

la solución de **eberlast** funciono correctamente, agrego las llamadas

> using System.Net;
>   using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
>   using System.Net.Security;
>
> ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors){ return true; };

Answer (score 1):

Mismo problema en 25/06/2021, lo solucioné aquí en el foro.

Únicamente agregué una línea de código previo a mi cliente para enviar el correo, forzando a reconocer el certificado. para ello debemos utilizar la siguiente paquetería

```
     using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
     using System.Net.Security;

     //Método que contiene nuestro código para el correo
     try
        {

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate 
                (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            
            Cliente.Send(Mensajecorreo);
            MessageBox.Show("Correo Enviado");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error " + e);

        }
        finally
        {
            //Desechamos los datos almacenados y limpiamos los campos
            Mensajecorreo.Dispose();
            Cliente.Dispose();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero le sirva a alguien más